# TopShelfでアプリ内部からアプリ終了する手段が知りたい

Tags: c#

TopShelfを使用するとコンソールアプリが永続サービス化する認識です。
コンソールアプリの外側からアプリ終了すれば、TopShelfのWhenStopedイベントが検知するので問題なく終了できます。
しかし、アプリ内部のイベントでアプリ終了したい場合、TopShelfのイベントループを終わらせる指示をアプリ内部から発行しないといけないと考えていますが、その手段が分かりません。

環境：Visualstudio2019、C＃、TopShelf 4.3.1-develop.253

Comment: この辺の記事の組み合わせや内容を読み解くと参考になるかもしれません。[Getting a Topshelf service to run once on boot, then stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23391097/9014308), [How to catch exception and stop Topshelf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23791696/9014308), [Restarting a c# TopShelf service programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24915082/9014308), [TopShelf service stuck in 'Stopping' state on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25878662/9014308)

Comment: これら記事の情報は公式リファレンスにない超重要な情報ですね。
解決できそうなので、解決手段まとめ次第回答記載します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下解決手段です。コードサンプルとシーケンスを添付します。

1.TopShelfのWhenStartedイベント時に動作する、XXXXServiceクラスのStart()の引数でHostControlのインスタンスを渡す。
HostControlはTopShelfのイベントループを操作できるクラスのようです。
2.XXXXServiceクラスではStart()時に渡されたHostControlインスタンスを、内部に保持しておく
3.アプリ終了したいタイミングでHostControl.stop()を呼ぶ
4.WhenStoppedイベントに定義したXXXXService.Stop()が呼ばれ、XXXXService.Stop()の処理終了と同時にアプリ終了する

**コードサンプル**

```
    public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<XXXXService>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new XXXXService());
                s.WhenStarted((service, hostControl) =>
                {
                    return service.Start(hostControl);
                });
                s.WhenStopped(service => service.Stop());
            });
            //Windowsサービスの設定
           x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            x.SetDescription("This is XXXXService");
            x.SetDisplayName("XXXXService");
            x.SetServiceName("XXXXService");
        });
    }
}
```

**アプリ内部からの終了シーケンス**

[image: TopShelf アプリ内部からの終了シーケンス]

Comment: HostControl.stop()を呼んだ後XXXXService.Stop()は非同期で走るため、XXXXService内のリソースのデッドロックや破棄漏れに注意が必要です。